# Program type already present: com.bumptech.glide.MemoryCategory

Tags: java, android

I am building an application using google places API. As the places API is deprecated I tried to change the code but now I am having
 Program type already present: com.bumptech.glide.MemoryCategory 
error

I have removed

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

and included

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

in xml

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name=
"com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
  />
```

also imported

```
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.Autocomplete;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity;
import 
com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.model.AutocompleteActivityMode;
```

build: app

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    //
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

autocompleteFragment code

```
  if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "api key");
        }
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                destination = place.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: shere the app level `bulid.gradle`

Comment: Share a fragment of your logcat, the part that shows the exceptoin.

Comment: @rachna patwal try to replace the `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'` to `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'`
clean and rebuild again

Comment: I removed the library and everything works fine.